# c# windows mobile Text messaging

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, text, message

I have mad an application for windows mobile which can do different mobile functions with the numbers the application has.

Anyway. I want to start the Text message application and send a phonenumber as an argument.
I have only found this:

```
             SmsMessage sms = new SmsMessage();

            sms.Body = "This is a message";
            sms.To.Add(new Recipient(sNumber));
            sms.Send();
```

But i want to use the text messaging application in the mobile device. 
Any tip?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As a start, have you looked to see if [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxcompact/thread/cf8f98a2-8fbb-4465-aced-e8602c38dded) is relevant to what you want to do? One thing it mentions is using [CE MAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415647.aspx) and COM interop. There's also the [Mobile In The Hand](http://inthehand.com/content/Mobile.aspx) library.

There are other links in that discussion too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MessagingApplication class, in particular its [DisplayComposeForm static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms882005.aspx). You should be able to use a code snippet such as the following to get the built in messaging application to appear.

```
  SmsMessage sms = new SmsMessage();

  sms.Body = "This is a message";
  sms.To.Add(new Recipient(sNumber));
  MessagingApplication.DisplayComposeForm(sms);
```

I also have a blog post available with a sample application that in part demonstrates using this API - http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/495.